# How to set column name from column value in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a data frame that looks like the following.

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0: 2 | 57: 9 | None | 436: 77 | 11469: 1018 | 203: 44 |
| 0: 0 | 57: 15 | None | 436: 47 | None | 203: 89 |
| 0: 45 | 57: 0 | 11469: 1116 | 436: 7 | None | 203: 0 |
| 0: 1 | 57: 23 | None | 436: 0 | 11469: 18 | None |
| 0: 23 | 57: 5 | None | 436: 63 | None | 203: 4 |

Here, the column values represent the distance and time, in meters and seconds (`57: 9` means `57` meters and `9` seconds). I want to rename my column such that the **meter value** becomes **column name** and the **seconds value** remains as a **column value**. Moreover, the columns where values are None, they should be replaced by Zero (0).

Desired output:

| 0 | 57 | 11469 | 436 | 11469 | 203 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 9 | 0 | 77 | 1018 | 44 |
| 0 | 15 | 0 | 47 | 0 | 89 |
| 45 | 0 | 1116 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 23 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 0 |
| 23 | 5 | 0 | 63 | 0 | 4 |

I am new to python so I don't know how I can achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split each column by `:`  with select last splitted values and replace to missing values, for columns forward filling missing values with select last row and after split select first values:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(': ').str[-1]).fillna(0)
df1.columns = df.ffill().iloc[-1].str.split(': ').str[0].tolist()
print (df1)
    0  57 11469 436 11469 203
0   2   9     0  77  1018  44
1   0  15     0  47     0  89
2  45   0  1116   7     0   0
3   1  23     0   0    18   0
4  23   5     0  63     0   4
```

Comment: And what about `NaN` values? How I can replace NaN with 0?

Comment: @ZunairaSaid - anwer was edited.